# Selectbox with Timezones in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, drop-down-menu

I want to make selectbox like [this](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-n6unJHw35bE/ToImfzoQA7I/AAAAAAAAAns/T4A3nkGpWnc/1317152387178.png) with simple_form (but it doesn't matter I think). I found that in Rails 2.1 was object TimeZone.us_zones but now it doesn't work neither Time.zone.all or smth. The line example for simple_form:

```
  = f.time_zone :time_zone, TimeZone.us_zones
```

And I should have a time_zone field string format in db sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works without any collection

```
  = f.time_zone_select :time_zone
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be helpful as well

```
<li> <%= f.label :time_zone %><%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, :class => :timezone %> </li>
```